# Which syntax to use to access variable in js (through webpack) that has been passed from flask (if double curly brackets don't work)?

Tags: javascript, flask, webpack, jinja2

In **flask app** I pass my variable like that:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    myvar = 1
    return render_template('index.html', myvar=myvar)
```

In my **index.html** I have:

```
<script src='static/bundle/index.js'></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
const newvar = {{ myvar }};
console.log(myvar);
</script>
```

In my **static/bundle/index.js** it's all the packages that are imported (if I import them directly in index.html via script tag, then it throughs an error)

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {bundle: './app/static/js/app.js',
          index: path.join(__dirname, './app/static/index.js'),},
  resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/static/bundle/')
  }
};
```

So when I try to access a variable in my **./app/static/index.js** file with standard jinja syntax and run `npm run build`:

```
const newvar = {{ myvar }};
console.log(myvar);
```

It throughs an error:

```
ERROR in ./app/static/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|     const newvar = {{ myvar }};
|     console.log(newvar);
|
```